# Cannot log mongoose model attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

***This is a problem with my mongoose model.find code at the bottom***

Pasted below is my node.js code using mongoose to interact with MongoDB. For some reason, when I run it I get the following result:

```
    Starting...
(node:7863) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoInvalidArgumentError: Method "collection.find()" accepts at most two arguments
    at Collection.find (/Users/justing/Documents/WebDev/FruitsProject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:238:19)
    at NativeCollection.<computed> [as find] (/Users/justing/Documents/WebDev/FruitsProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:191:33)
    at NativeCollection.Collection.doQueue (/Users/justing/Documents/WebDev/FruitsProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/collection.js:135:23)
    at /Users/justing/Documents/WebDev/FruitsProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/collection.js:82:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7863) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7863) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What I should see is the name attribute of an instance of the Fruit model. I've tried substituting in {} for argument #1, as per documentation but I can't seem to get the desired result, which is just to console.log them.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
console.log("Starting...");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser:true});

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit ({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty solid as a fruit."
});

fruit.save();

 Fruit.find({},function(err,fruits){
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
   } else {
     console.log(fruits);
     fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
       console.log(fruit.name);
     });
   }
  });
```

Comment: Try adding an `await` keyword before `Fruit.find`, a lot of these methods return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no error in your code, but if this code runs multiple times, you should define your Fruit Schema in another file because you cannot redefine the same schema in running time.

Comment: @JuanHuandred like he said its extremely common to have a schema in a file and require it in another file.